# select html element by its full html tag - JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to be able to select an HTML element by its tag, like:

```
document.querySelector("<div id='myDiv'\>hello world</div\>")
//instead of: document.querySelector("#myDiv")
```

However, this code returns an error. The code should return the HTML element.

Does anybody know a way to achieve this? (vanilla JS preferred)

Comment: You can't do it. query selectors are CSS selectors, not HTML tags.

Comment: What is the use case? I'm sure something can be done to accomplish what you actually need

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit odd that you wouldn't want to select element via ID. But regardless one way of selecting the element in your example would be to look for its innerHTML.

e.g

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i=0;i<div.length;i++){
   console.log(div[i].innerHTML)
   if(div [i].innerHTML == 'hello world'){
       var element = div[i].parentElement
       console.log(element)
       break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `outerHTML` to search for it, however this only works if the element has a parent element.

```js
var els = Array.from(document.querySelector('body *')); //this selects all elements in the body
var el;
for(var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if(els.outerHTML === "<div id='myDiv'\>hello world</div\>") {
    el = els[i];
  }
}
//Use the el variable for your element
```